# Why the separator not working when there is concatenation?

Tags: python, concatenation

When using print function with + or *, there is no way to use the sep argument.

For example:

`print("panda", "panda", sep=", ")`

gives:

panda, panda

however

using

`print("panda" + "panda", sep=", ")`

or

`print("panda" * 2, sep=", ")`

gives:

pandapanda

why?

I know, probably the answer "because Python is designed so". But what is the deeper explanation?

Comment: Because anything else would make absolutely **no sense**. 2+2=4, 2*2=4, but `print(2,2)` results in `2 2`. `print` is simply not + or * .

Comment: `"panda" + "panda"` results in a single string as does `"panda" * 2`. There is nothing to apply the separator to.

Comment: Because all `print` gets to see is `"pandapanda"`. `print` isn't aware of what expressions you're evaluating within its calling code, it just gets the result of those expressions as arguments.

Comment: So concatenation makes a new string, so there is no sense for separator, as this is one string, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

```
print("panda" + "panda", sep=", ")
```

is the same as

```
s = "panda" + "panda"
print(s, sep=", ")
```

In both cases you are only passing a single string to be printed. There are not multiple strings that need to be separated by `sep=", "`.

To test your understanding see if you can predict what this will print:

```
print("panda" + "panda", "panda", sep=", ")
```

> `pandapanda, panda`

Answer (score 0):

The `print` function is designed to work with multiple inputs. When you pass multiple arguments to the `print` function using commas, each argument is treated as a separate value to be printed. The `sep` argument specifies the separator to be used between these values.

In the case of `print("panda", "panda", sep=", ")`, you provided two inputs: the first "panda" and the second "panda". The `sep` argument is set to ", ", so the output will be the first input followed by the separator and then the second input. This results in the output: `"panda, panda"`.

However, when you use the `+` operator to concatenate two strings, or the `*` operator to repeat a string, the resulting expression is a single string. In the case of `print("panda" + "panda", sep=", ")`, the expression `"panda" + "panda"` evaluates to "pandapanda", which is a single input. Since you provided only one input, the `sep` argument does not have any effect in this case.

Similarly, `print("panda" * 2, sep=", ")` evaluates to "pandapanda", which is again a single string. Since there are no separate values to be separated by the `sep` argument, it does not have any effect.

So, the `sep` argument works when you pass multiple arguments to the `print` function, but it does not have any effect when you have a single input that is already a concatenated or repeated string.